# why display error as "unknown issue with google play service" while google+ integration?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus

I am working on google+ integration in android.I Integrate all setting and code.but it will display error as unknown issue with google play service.
how can i resolve?

my code as below:

```
 google_api_client =  new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API,Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
```

**Your answer would be appreciated**

Comment: Post the error in the logcat.

Comment: it will display dialog after G+ login process but it will not go for result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the  [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#set_up_google_sign-in_for_google) in Google Developers Console. Under `API Manager`, select `Credentials` then the OAuth consent screen tab, put all necessary credentials.

If you haven't already registered your application with the Google Developers Console then set up a project and application in the Developers Console

In a terminal, run the Keytool utility to get the `SHA1` fingerprint for your digitally signed .apk file's public certificate.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

Authorization for the Google Drive Android API is handled by the  [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient). This is typically created in an activity's onCreate() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstance);

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
}
```

After you create the client, you must connect it for authorization to occur.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```